# What is "How do you keep yourself up to date regarding the new languages and frameworks that are currently on the market?" really asking?

Tags: interviewing

I was interviewed for a QA position, and the HR Recruiter asked:

> How do you keep yourself up to date regarding the new languages and frameworks that are currently on the market?

What sort of responses are interviewers looking for when asking this question?

Should I tell about how I study or learn the languages and frameworks each day?

Comment: If you tell them you only learn new languages and new frameworks while you're at work from 9 to 5, and that at night, you do not have time to study because you have a girlfriend, do not expect to get the job. Instead, tell them that you compete in hackathons on the weekends, go to technical meetups once in a while, and study programming at night. That being said, don't just tell them this. Do it a few times as well. If they ask you questions about the latest hackathon you've participated in or the latest technical meetup you attended, you'll need to be able to talk about those things.

Comment: I've edited your question to try and clarify what you are asking, so we can perhaps reopen this. Hopefully this new version still aligns with your intent, if not feel free to edit it again.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that there are several things going on...

First, the interviewer may be probing for a technology enthusiast.  A lot of companies give extra weight to a candidate who do independent study, or have github projects, or the like.  The theory there being they want someone who is *so excited* about technology that they just can't stop once that 5pm whistle goes off.  So, if you do have any such projects/interests, it's proper to bring them up.

Second, as other have said, interviewer may be probing for your learning style.  How *do* you learn a new language or framework anyway?  Me, I pick a project that is interesting.  Say, make my own version of a favorite childhood video game.  Some people like to work through tutorials.  My boy prefers to work through K&R [1] -- mostly because I pay him for the completed exercises...  ;D

Third, interviewer is *explicitly* asking you if you **do** keep up with new trends.  Again, on the theory that such people will be enthusiastic technologists.  If you do, it can't hurt you to bring it up.  If you don't, you could speak to when technology advances introduced themselves to *you*, specifically at work.

[1]   K&R is an old nickname for the first book describing the C language. It was written by Kernighan and Ritchie, published 1978, and titled "The C Programming Language". It is much beloved, and has graced the lives of generations of students. Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language . The book contains the original "Hello, World" program!

Comment: Can you explain what K&R is in the answer? It's a little confusing right now.

Comment: @Erik Probably refers to a book or tutorial for kids to learn programming.

Comment: @Erik K&R is an old nickname for the first book describing the C language.  It was written by Kernighan and Ritchie, published 1978, and titled "The C Programming Language".  It is much beloved, and has graced the lives of generations of students.  Link:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language.  The book contains the **original** "Hello, World" program!

Answer (score 3):

> Do this question means that I´ve tell with HR recruitment about how I
>   study or learn the languages and frameworks in day by day?

Yes.

I always ask candidates how they like to learn new things. Some prefer to read. Some prefer to go to training classes. Some prefer to be mentored one-on-one. Some prefer to download and try things on their own, etc.

Talk about how you like to learn, and how you learn best. Give some examples of things you have recently learned, and how they have benefited you on the job (and preferably in the job you are applying for).

Comment: I do understand differently the question from the OP post that *ask candidates how they like to learn new things*. From the OP post I understand "how do you follow the trend ?" Which I answer in a polite way *I don't and I don't care of the current trend, I use appropriate and mature enough technologies to solve my current problem*. And answering to *how I like to learn new things* would lead to a different answer from me.

Answer (score 0):

It means,

> "Do you take care of your knowledge in this area? Do you nurture it,
>   improve it or otherwise care that it gets extinguished through time?"

It's asking you how you're maintaining relevancy in a changing field. Very easy to answer, very easy to get wrong too. Just show that you're following the media and/or updates of that field. This would be something akin to following a dev blog you enjoy or Hacker News in your down time.